# How to query the first data value in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I already know that to query the latest data, I can use `last` command in Apache IoTDB. However, what command can I use to query the first data in IoTDB? Also, how can I query the first and last value in one statement of IoTDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `order by time limit 1` statement to see if you get the first value of time series in Apache IoTDB. If you want to query the first value and last value at the same time, you can try to use `FIRST_VALUE` function.